# Can't exit a loop after all checks return false

Tags: php, loops, docker, symfony, foreach

I have some methods that checks the response of a command, and based on that response, will do something else, or fail.

I have got it to where it checks the command output and returns false but then proceeds to carry on executing the rest of the code.

Here's some code

```
public function upgradeImages($images)
{
    $this->pull($images);

    echo "Do next method - Fake destroy\n";

    echo "Do next method - Fake re-build\n";
}

public function pull($images)
{
    // Count how many containers will be attempted to be updated
    $countImages = count($images);

    echo("Updrading $countImages containers...");

    foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        $key = $key + 1;

        // Is there a new version of the image?
        if ($this->isNewVersion($image)) {
            echo("($key/$countImages) Upgrading '$image'");

            $this->docker('pull ' . $image);
        }

        echo("'$image' is at the latest version");
    }
}

public function isNewVersion($image)
{
    $cmdOutput = (new Process($this->docker('pull ' . $image)));
    $cmdOutput->start();

    $cmdOutput->wait(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (contains($buffer, 'Image is up to date')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

What's happening here is, `upgradeImage` runs the `pull` method and the `pull` method is checking an array of Docker images and looping through to see if the image has a new version. That is done by running the `isNewVersion()` method, which is checking the `$buffer` for the output and comparing it.

If `isNewVersion()` returns true, it will loop through and update the images.

If `isNewVersion()` returns false, it lets you know with a message saying it's up-to-date.

If the method is returning false, I want the loop to exit after *ALL* checks have taken place and not continue to run the code in the `upgradeImages` method after `$this->pull()`. If I add an `exit` after the check, it will exit after the first check and not check the rest of the loop.

Assuming I chose 2 images to update and both did *not* need to be updated, the output would be like so:

```
Updrading 2 containers...
'composer:latest' is at the latest version
'php:7.2-fpm-alpine' is at the latest version
Fake destroy
Fake re-build
```

Comment: Could you provide an example output?

Comment: Updated post with some output

Comment: I see, and in this case, would the desired behavior be to not run the destroy and re-build?

Comment: Correct, if there are no images to update, the destroy/re-build methods need not be run

Comment: Have you considered writing your logic with ansible instead of PHP? It could make your life easier and you would get idempotency more or less for free. e.g. pulling an image via ansible can be archived by utilizing the docker_image module described here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html?highlight=docker_image

Comment: I have not. Not something that fits my use case I don't think. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
public function upgradeImages($images)
{
    $imagesUpdated = $this->pull($images);

    if ($imagesUpdated > 0) {
        echo "Do next method - Fake destroy\n";

        echo "Do next method - Fake re-build\n";

    } else {
        // do nothing or explicit call 'exit' if you want
    }


}

public function pull($images)
{
    // Count how many containers will be attempted to be updated
    $countImages = count($images);
    $countUpdated = 0;
    echo("Updrading $countImages containers...");

    foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        $key = $key + 1;

        // Is there a new version of the image?
        if ($this->isNewVersion($image)) {
            echo("($key/$countImages) Upgrading '$image'");

            $this->docker('pull ' . $image);
            $countUpdated++;
        }

        echo("'$image' is at the latest version");
    }
    return $countUpdated;
}

public function isNewVersion($image)
{
    $cmdOutput = (new Process($this->docker('pull ' . $image)));
    $cmdOutput->start();

    $cmdOutput->wait(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (contains($buffer, 'Image is up to date')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: This way worked for me and I like it. Going to dig into it more and see if it's fit for purpose. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

The method `upgradeImages` can have more than one destroy/re-build. Instead of doing that within `pull`, create another method that can be called multiple times.  I have named it `doUpgrade()` and am passing it the `$image` to upgrade.

```
public function upgradeImages($images)
{
    $this->pull($images);
}

public function doUpgrade($image)
{
    echo "Do next method - Fake destroy\n";
    echo "Do next method - Fake re-build\n";
}

public function pull($images)
{
    // Count how many containers will be attempted to be updated
    $countImages = count($images);

    echo("Updrading $countImages containers...");

    foreach ($images as $key => $image) {
        $key = $key + 1;

        // Is there a new version of the image?
        if ($this->isNewVersion($image)) {
            echo("($key/$countImages) Upgrading '$image'");

            $this->docker('pull ' . $image);

            /* call the destroy/re-build */
            echo("'$image' being upgraded");
            $this->doUpgrade($image);
        }

        echo("'$image' is at the latest version");
    }
}

public function isNewVersion($image)
{
    $cmdOutput = (new Process($this->docker('pull ' . $image)));
    $cmdOutput->start();

    $cmdOutput->wait(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if (contains($buffer, 'Image is up to date')) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that return in the first iteration of the `foreach` loop, breaking it? I think it will be better if you declare `$ret = false;` at the beginning of the function, assigning `true` to it only when needed (if image is updated), and then returning `return $ret;` outside the `foreach` loop, that way you are sure it will only be true is an image was in deed updated.

Comment: But it will return. A return is a return, you cannot 'undo' a return. I still thinks that the best approach will be looping through the array in the first function, and calling the next function inside the loop from the first function.

Comment: I tried this method and it works well - does what I need. Gonna look into it more and if it is fit for purpose I'll mark as the best answer. Though this situation might not be best for anyone else with a similar issue, it did help me with mine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your problem (Can't exit a loop after all checks return false)
If you want to stop the execution if it meets your requirements in the conditions, You can force to stop it using Break;

Check for more info
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: I tried this. It seemed no matter where I put it, it didn't work. Perhaps you have some examples of best use case?